# where can I find the commands for the startup programs in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: startup

Where can I find the commands for the startup programs? The name part is easy but I have no clue about where the commands are. Browsing option does not help much.
I'd like to have at start Chromium, Audio recorder, Focus Writer, SD card, Sound setting.

I am looking for the commands to enter in the command box of the Startup Applications. The question "How do I start applications automatically on login?" does not explain how to show the Main Menu.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by startup.  There are many startup programs and services, some so subtle that you it's unlikely that you're even considering them in your question.  There are programs that checks and loads the OS.  Checks and mounts the configured file systems.  There are programs that loads the network drivers and connect to the network.  There are programs that runs before the GUI login and programs that decide which GUI.  If you specify something that you want to do with this information it would make ti clearer what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you saying you want Chromium to automatically be started when you boot your computer?  Are you saying you want the recorder to automatically be recording when you turn on your computer?  Karel gave a link of now to auto start the programs.  There are commands to find the physical location of the programs that can be answered if that's your specific question.

Comment: Do you want those programs to be started automatically at log in or do you 'only' want buttons in the panel for a quick start (without having to search for them via dash (the button with the Ubuntu symbol in the top left corner)?

Comment: I want those programs to be started automatically at log in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the links to start installed graphical programs (that you can drag to the launcher bar or copy + paste to your desktop), they are in the directory `/usr/share/applications/` and end with the suffix `.desktop`.

Example for automounting disks with *Startup Applications* :
`udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/01D0EED1CBC97EE0`.
The hexadecimal UUID can be found with terminal command: `ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/`.

Answer (score 0):

I partially found what I was looking for: for example to have Sound settings at log in, I dragged the Sound Settings icon onto the Startup Applications window. The result in the command box is: `unity-control-center sound`.

This does not work for the SD Card icon though.